# SQL Query for .005

Tags: sql

I want to be able to do a SQL Query that gets all numbers that end in .005

```
Select * from amount where (numbers end in X.XX5)
```

I don't care what the numbers are for X

Comment: Are there any digits possible after the 5?  ie. 0.12589

Comment: What data type is the number column?  Text, numeric?

Comment: You can user substring functions (or right()) for this as well...syntax varies depending on what database you are using though.  Pending what DB you are using... right(numbers,4) gives you the right 4 chars...combine left and right to get to the decimal. 'where Left(right(numbers,4,1) = '.' and right(numbers,1) = '5'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming you don't care what the first and second digit after the decimal is.Try this:

```
select * from MyTable where MyField like '%.__5'
```

The % specifies a substitution for 0 or more characters, and the underscores are a substitute for a single character.

If there are digits after the 5, use

```
 select * from MyTable where MyField like '%.__5%'
```

Comment: Yours is the only answer so far that fufills the OP's needs.

Comment: What is the data type of `MyField`?

Comment: It won't matter whether it is a varchar or a decimal, this query will return what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @gwin003 What about `float` or `double`?

Comment: It won't work if the implicit conversion of number to string results in a string in the format 'X,XX5' as it will do in certain locales.

Comment: @Colin'tHart I agree, but does your example apply to this situation?

Comment: Yes. The use of the string comparison operator `like` will cause the DBMS to do an implicit conversion of the number to a string. This will use commas for the decimal separator in certain locales.

Comment: There's also a question how **numeric** `0.00499999999` should be matched. What will be the result? Can you predict it for every SQL implementation?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM amount WHERE numbers LIKE '%.005';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
  Select * from amount where number like '%.005'
```

or

```
  Select * from amount where number like '%.005%'
```

Considering the data type of `number` as `string`

Comment: What is the data type of `amount`?

Comment: @PM77-1:- amount is the table which I have considered!!1

Comment: Sorry, I mean `numbers`.

Comment: It actually doesn't matter if `number` is a string.